# How to add new child node to existing child node

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I need to make a car a child node of a track. I have looked online, and have tried several different ways, but I can't get it to work properly.

Here is my xml file I generate.

```
<RTDX msgid="3642728b-b75c-4196-9fad-5c4e882c3a9d" msgtime="0001-01-01 00:00:00.000" xmlns="http://www.aps-technology.com">
    <EventTime>2012-02-09 19:38:13.802</EventTime>
    <Track name="P7E Switch" />
    <Car name="CSXT8423" sequence="4" orientation="A" axles="1" />
</RTDX>
```

however this is the expected format.

```
<RTDX msgid="3642728b-b75c-4196-9fad-5c4e882c3a9d" msgtime="0001-01-01 00:00:00.000" xmlns="http://www.aps-technology.com">
    <EventTime>2011-12-07 05:00:03.579</EventTime>
    <Track name="P7E Switch">
        <Car name="CSXT8423" sequence="1" orientation="A"/>
    </Track>
</RTDX>
```

This is my method that generates the Xml File. Note that the first line of the message is generated elsewhere and I cannot change that.

```
protected override void SaveApsXml(System.Xml.XmlNode node)
{
    base.SaveApsXml(node);            
    node.AppendNewChild("EventTime").SetElementText(this.EventTime.ToString(ApsMessage.DateTimeFormat));
    node.AppendNewChild("Track").SetAttribute("name", this.Track); //Pretty sure this is whats causing the problem
    this.SequenceCar.SaveApsXml(node.AppendNewChild("Car"));
}
```

For reference this is the AppendNewChild Method

```
public static XmlNode AppendNewChild(this XmlNode node, string name)
{
    XmlNode child = node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(name, node.NamespaceURI);
    return node.AppendChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because you're appending the car to the wrong node.

```
protected override void SaveApsXml(System.Xml.XmlNode node)
{
    base.SaveApsXml(node);            
    node.AppendNewChild("EventTime").SetElementText(this.EventTime.ToString(ApsMessage.DateTimeFormat));
    var track = node.AppendNewChild("Track");
    track.SetAttribute("name", this.Track);
    this.SequenceCar.SaveApsXml(track.AppendNewChild("Car"));
}
```

Also note that your expected format-example is incorrect xml (root element name doesn't match - RTDX vs RTDT).

Comment: Thank you so much, that seemed to address my problem!
As for the miss matched format, I accidently posted the older format. I'll update it now.